# If $R$ is a Noetherian ring then $R[[x]]$ is also Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, formal-power-series

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. How can one prove that the ring of the formal power series $R[[x]]$ is again a Noetherian ring?

It is well-known that the ring of polynomials $R[x]$ is Noetherian. I try imitating the standard proof of the fact by replacing "leading coefficients" by "lowest coefficients", but it does not work.

Comment: Also, see Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, p 16. You can see his argument at the preview: http://books.google.com/books/about/Commutative_Ring_Theory.html?id=yJwNrABugDEC

Answer (score 17):

Step 1: Let $f\in R[[x]]$ such that the constant term of $f$ is a unit. Then $f$ is a unit. It's an easy exercise to construct $f^{-1}$ term-by-term.

Step 2: Show that if $I$ is an ideal, the set of coefficients of lowest nonzero terms of elements of $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Step 3: Consider an ascending chain of ideal. $I_1\subset I_2\subset\ldots$, and let $J_1\subset J_2\subset\ldots$ be the corresponding chain of ideals in $R$, where $J_i$ is the ideal of coefficients of lowest nonzero terms of elements of $I_i$.

Step 4: $J_1\subset J_2\subset\ldots$ can only be strict inclusion at finitely many places. The only other way to have strict inclusion in $I_1\subset I_2\subset\ldots$ is via the lowest degree in $x$ of nonzero terms, which can only decrease finitely many times.

Comment: @BrettFrankel How does it follow that $I_i \subset I_{i+1}?$

Comment: @TheSubstitute The ascending chain $I_i$ is given.

Comment: Why can't we have a strict inclusion $I_1 \subset I_2$ with both having the same lowest degree of nonzero elements and the same leading coefficients?(Say $3x^4+x^5 \in I_2 \setminus I_1$ but $3x^4+x^6 \in I_1$)

Comment: How can you define "*the set of the lowest nonzero terms of elements of $I$*"? A typical element in $I$ is of the form $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_ix^i$. Indeed, there're elements that haven't "lowest nonzero term" (such as $a=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty x^i$).

Comment: @J.Doe $R[[x]]$ is the set of formal power series with non-negative powers by definition.

Answer (score 15):

Hilbert's basis theorem can be adapted for formal power series. I found a .pdf on the internet that describes the process well, if you look at section 8.2.3: [here.](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter8.pdf)

Basically, you simply replace the degree of the polynomial with the lowest degree in the power series.

Comment: This link appears to be broken. [Here's an archived version due to the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230608074050/https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter8.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

If $f\in R[[x]]$, we write $o(f)$ for the degree of the first nonzero term of $f$ and $c(f)$ for the first nonzero coefficient of $f$.  Let $I\subseteq R[[x]]$ be an ideal and let $$I_n=\{c(f):f\in I, o(f)=n\}\cup\{0\}.$$  Then each $I_n$ is an ideal in $R$ and $$I_0\subseteq I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq\dots.$$  Since $R$ is Noetherian, there is some $N$ such that $I_n=I_N$ for all $n\geq N$.  Also, each $I_n$ is finitely generated.  So we can pick finitely many elements $a_1,\dots,a_m\in I$ which witness finite generating sets of $I_n$ for each $n\leq N$.  Let $J$ be the ideal generated by $a_1,\dots,a_m$.  Then for any $f\in I$, there exists $g\in J$ such that $o(f)=o(g)$ and $c(f)=c(g)$ (if $o(f)\leq N$ this is by definition of $J$, and if $o(f)>N$ this follows from the case $o(f)=N$ by multiplying by $x^{o(f)-N}$ since $I_{o(f)}=I_N$).  In other words, we can match the first nonzero term of any element of $I$ with an element of $J$.

We now iterate this to realize an entire element of $I$ as an element of $J$.  We start with $f=f_0\in I$ and pick $g_0\in J$ such that $o(g_0)=o(f_0)$ and $c(g_0)=c(f_0)$.  Now let $f_1=f_0-g_0$; by our choice of $g_0$ we have $o(f_1)>o(f_0)$.  Choose $g_1$ such that $o(g_1)=o(f_1)$ and $c(g_1)=c(f_1)$, and let $f_2=f_1-g_1$.  Repeating this process, we get a sequence of elements $f_n\in I$ and $g_n\in J$ with $f_{n+1}=f_n-g_n$ and $o(f_n)=o(g_n)\geq n$ for each $n$.  In particular, this implies $f_n\to 0$ in the $x$-adic topology so $\sum_n g_n$ converges to $f$.  Moreover, if we write $g_n=\sum b_{in} a_i$, each coefficient $b_{in}$ is divisible by $x^{n-N}$ since $o(a_i)\leq N$ for each $i$ and $o(g_n)\geq n$.  It follows that $\sum_n b_{in}$ converges for each $i$ and we can write $f=\sum g_n=\sum_i(\sum_n b_{in})a_i$.   Thus $f\in J$.  Since $f\in I$ was arbitrary, this means $I=J$ so $I$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I am not sure about the definition of $J$ as the ideal of $R[[x]]$ generated by $a_1,...,a_m$ and trying to show that $I=J$, since the $a_i$ themselves are in general not in $I$.  For example, in $R[[x]]=\Bbb Z[[x]]$, take the principal ideal $I$ generated by $f_0=2+3x$.  Then every $f\in I$ has $c(f)$ is divisible by 2 and $I_0=I_1=\cdots=(2)$, but $f_0$ is not in the ideal of $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ generated by $2$, as the $x$ coefficient of $f_0$ is not even.  Maybe one needs to instead take specific elements of $I$ that have $c(f)=a_i$ and $o(f)$ minimal, or something like that.

Comment: Oops, the $a_i$ were supposed to be in $I$, not in $R$ (i.e., what you suggested in your last sentence).

Comment: I feel confused on the notation of indices like the $n$ used in $I_n$ and the $n$ used in $n\geq N$ everywhere. I was assuming the latter one can be replaced by new notation $i\geq N$ and $$I_0\leq I_1 \leq\cdots\leq I_{i}=I_{i+1}=\cdots$$@EricWofsey Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: @N00BMaster: Sure, you can use a different letter instead of $n$ if you prefer.